# Android App with model.tflite for object detection

Tags: java, android, android-studio, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I had trained my dataset and got a model with extension 'tflite'; I put it in [this Anrdoid project](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android).

Bu then I received this error:

> Input tensor has type kTfLiteFloat32: it requires specifying
> Normalization Options metadata to preprocess input images.

I don't know how to fix this, and I hope that you could help me.

Comment: This project has been updated and uses Task Library as first option. Either you insert metadata to your tflite file or change the build variant and use the other option with Interpreter and Support Library. At second option you will use custom pre and post processing.